# Attempting to download and save an image to a ImageField is failing

Tags: django

The offending code:

```
file_name = os.path.basename(image_url)
downloaded = urllib2.urlopen(image_url).read()
image_file = File(downloaded, name=file_name)
image_file.size = len( downloaded )

model = BlogPost()
model.image.save(file_name, image_file)
model.save()
```

Model:

class BlogPost(models.Model):
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='blog-image',
                              help_text='Feature image',
                              blank=True,
                              null=True)

I'm getting this:

```
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'read'
```

If I delete the line image_file.size:

```
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'name'
```

`downloaded` is populated, so it has successfully downloaded the file.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

The issue was that File needs more than just the content. Instead of trying to use `File` and doing this:

```
image_file = File(downloaded, name=file_name)
image_file.size = len( downloaded )
```

I should use ContentFile and do this:

```
image_file = ContentFile(downloaded)
```

From the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/files/file/#the-contentfile-class):

> The ContentFile class inherits from File, but unlike File it operates on string content, rather than an actual file.